# A "non-abelian excision" statement for mapping out of a space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology

Let $U \subset A \subset X$ be spaces (in the sense of homotopy theory). 
For every pointed space $Y$ restriction maps induce the following canonical map between mapping spaces:

$$fiber(Map(X,Y) \to Map(A, Y)) \to fiber(Map(X-U,Y) \to Map(A-U,Y))$$

**Is this map a homotopy equivalence?** If not, can we give necessary and sufficient conditions (on $X, A, U$ and $Y$) for when it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "subspace" and "fiber". Let me put some theorems down for you:

**Theorem**: Let $U,V\subseteq X$ open subspaces. Then the following is a homotopy pushout square:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U\cap V @>>> U\\
@VVV @VVV \\
V @>>> U\cup V
\end{CD}\,.$$
**Proof:** This is a particular case of proposition A.3.2 in Higher Algebra, applied to the cover $\{U,V\}$ of $U\cup V$.$\,.\square$

**Lemma:** The derived functor $\mathrm{Map}(-,Y)$ turns homotopy pushout squares into homotopy pullback squares.

**Proof:** Classical (for example Proposition 5.5.2.2 in Higher Topos Theory, but this must be already in Bousfield-Kan).$\,\square$

**Lemma:** Let

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P @>{f}>> X\\
@VVV @VVV \\
Y @>{g}>> Z
\end{CD}\,.$$
be a homotopy pullback square where $Z$ is pointed. Then the map
$$\mathrm{hofib}(f)\to \mathrm{hofib}(g)$$
is an equivalence.

**Proof:** Complete the square to a cube where the back face is

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{hofib}(f) @>>> *\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathrm{hofib}(g) @>>> *
\end{CD}\,.$$
Then this is a homotopy pullback square, since the top, bottom and front faces are homotopy pullback squares. Then the thesis follows immediately. $\,\square$

Putting the two previous lemmas together you see that what you want is true (at least regarding the homotopy fibers) if the square

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A\smallsetminus U @>>> A\\
@VVV @VVV \\
X\smallsetminus U @>>> X
\end{CD}\,.$$
is a homotopy pushout square. This happens if $X$ is a simplicial complex and  $A$ and $X\smallsetminus U$ are subcomplexes, or (by the previous theorem) if $A$ is open and $U$ is closed.

Comment: This is enough for what I needed, thanks!